# Automating CSV analysis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-glue, lowcode

My e-commerce company generates lots of CSV data. To track order status, the team must download a number of trackers. Creating a relationship and subsequently analyse,its a time-consuming process. Which AWS low-code solution can be used to **automate the workflow**?

Comment: What is the "workflow" that you would like to automate? Is it just using SQL against the CSV files, or does it involve moving files around? Do you need a User Interface? More information, please.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what 'workflow' you require, a few options are:

- [Amazon Honeycode](https://www.honeycode.aws/), which is a low-code application builder
- You can [Filter and retrieving data using Amazon S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html), which works on individual CSV files. This can be scripted via the AWS CLI or an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools)
- If you want to run SQL and create JOINs between multiple files, then **Amazon Athena** is fantastic. This, too, can be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly low code, AWS Athena uses SQL-like queries to analyze CSV files, among many other formats